# "long" dataframe to "transactions" for arules in R

Tags: r

I am working with the `arules Package in R`. I have a "long" dataframe `A` of transactions with two columns like this one:

`TID         itemNO
2393117   SJUMRE14E
2393118    ATVBCT14
2393127   L07EGG13E
2393128    MCM3100W
2393130 S1017501771
2393131     S6LN13X
2393133  SPCCLI551C
2393133 SPCPGI550BK
2393133  SPCCLI551Y
2393133  SPCCLI551C`

As we can see the last 4 items belong to one transaction and I need to convert it to a `"transaction"` class to work with in `apriori` function.
From what I have been able to find so far is thins way of converting this into `"transactions"` would be done in this manner

`TransAction <- as(split(A[,"itemNo"],A[,"TID"]), "transactions")`

However, since I have over 2.5 million transactions this is extreamly timeconsuming and this takes up to 1 hour. It is due to the `split()` function, is there any way of speeding up the process with `plyr` or `data.table` packages that could replace the `split()` function?

Comment: the transactions in your example you provided contain duplicates (e.g, the last row), in the original data you must have selected the unique transactions right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way I do it, and find it to be faster. Idea is to create a wide data frame of 0/1 values, and then feed that to create transactions. Does not require any split.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(arules)

df <- df %>%
  select(TID, itemNO) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  spread(itemNO, value, fill = 0)

itemMatrix <- as(as.matrix(df[, -1]), 'transactions')
```

Comment: This works perfect than you, takes around a minute to go through 2.5 million transactions which is a drastic change from what i had before

Comment: Best way to thank is to upvote the answer and accept it. :)